# Excel Formula - If 'string1' Or 'string2' then

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been checking out formulas for how to check a cell for specific text but am unsure of how to apply it to my worksheet.

In cell B20 I currently have `=B2`.

B2 can either be a 7-digit number (which is good) or it can be "Null" or "NoConnection".

What formula can I use to set B20 to 0 if either of the text strings are present in B2?

I have tried the below formula with no success.  Too many arguments error -

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Null",B2), 0,B2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
if(or(b2={"Null", "NoConnection"}), 0, b2)
```

Your formula would work for "Null" like this.

```
=if(isnumber(find("Null",B2)), 0, B2)
```

You just had a misplaced `)`.

Comment: Spot on!  Thanks for the quick reply Jeeped, I'll give you a tick in 5 minutes when it lets me.